# Accessing metadata for specific letters

Tags: fonts, xetex, metadata

- Do any font types store metadata about each letter?
- Or does Unicode provide any linguistic information about each symbol?
- Can this metadata be accessed in XeTeX?

Comment: It might be helpful to explain in more detail what metadata you have in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things I know:

- Use `\fontdimen` to get the dimensions of the font. See [TeX by Topic](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) 4.3 Font information.
- Use `\XeTeXglyphbounds` to get the boundingbox of every glyph. See [XeTeX Reference](http://ctan.org/pkg/xetexref).
- Use `\the\XeTeXcharclass ...` to get the predefined character class of a glyph. You can distinguish CJK characters (class 1), CJK punctuations (class 2 and 3) from normal characters (class 0). That's all XeTeX knows. For example,

  ```
  \the\XeTeXcharclass`a    % 0
  \the\XeTeXcharclass`文   % 1
  \the\XeTeXcharclass`《   % 2, should not be at the end of a line
  \the\XeTeXcharclass`。   % 3, should not be at the beginning of a line
  ```

I don't think there are linguistic information of each symbol.